# Colocar informação dentro do usuário especifico

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, microsoft-word

Preciso que o usuario cadastrado tenha acesso somente ao contrato dele
**usuario1 contrato1**
**usuario2 contrato2**

Ja tenho os contratos em .doc
Preciso que quando usuario logar no painel.php ele consiga ver o contrato dele em pdf ou em doc do word, que o usuario2 não consiga ver o contrtado do usuario1

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
 header('Location: index.php');
 exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query = "select usuario from usuario where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = md5('{$senha}')";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1) {
 $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
 header('Location: painel.php');
 exit();
} else {
 $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
 header('Location: index.php');
 exit();
}
login.php
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('verifica_login.php');
?>


<h2><a href="logout.php">Sair</a></h2>

painel.php
```

Comment: Tenta colocar aqui o código que você está usando para mostrar o contrato atualmente.
Mas, de qualquer forma, pensa que seu usuário fez login. Então, o ideal seria você ter os dados dele, e de contrato, devem estar no banco. Porque se você usar uma URL tipo sistema.com.br/contratoID/usuarioID fica pouco seguro

Comment: Estou utlizando um <iframe em html para puxar o contrato que está o codigo do cliente, queria poder colocar contrato dentro do banco de dados so que não faço ideia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia cadastrar no banco o caminho do documento em uma tabela separada com o ID referente ao usuário daquele documento.
No painel quando ele estiver logado você cruza esses IDs para fazer uma validação e exibe somente os documentos que baterem.
espero ter lhe ajudado.

```
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];

$texto = $_POST['texto'];

    $foto = $_FILES["foto"];

  // Recupera os dados dos campos

    $foto = $_FILES["foto"];



    // Se a foto estiver sido selecionada

    if (!empty($foto["name"])) {



        // Largura máxima em pixels

        $largura = 1500;

        // Altura máxima em pixels

        $altura = 1500;

        // Tamanho máximo do arquivo em bytes

        $tamanho = 10000000000000;



        $error = array();



        // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem

        if(!preg_match("/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/", $foto["type"])){

           $error[1] = "Isso não é uma imagem.";

        }



        // Pega as dimensões da imagem

        $dimensoes = getimagesize($foto["tmp_name"]);



        // Verifica se a largura da imagem é maior que a largura permitida

        if($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {

            $error[2] = "A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$largura." pixels";

        }



        // Verifica se a altura da imagem é maior que a altura permitida

        if($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {

            $error[3] = "Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$altura." pixels";

        }



        // Verifica se o tamanho da imagem é maior que o tamanho permitido

        if($foto["size"] > $tamanho) {

            $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no máximo ".$tamanho." bytes";

        }



        // Se não houver nenhum erro

        if (count($error) == 0) {



            // Pega extensão da imagem

            preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto["name"], $ext);



            // Gera um nome único para a imagem

            $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];



            // Caminho de onde ficará a imagem

            $caminho_imagem = "fotos/" . $nome_imagem;



            // Faz o upload da imagem para seu respectivo caminho

            move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);



            // Insere os dados no banco

        //  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES ('', '".$nome."', '".$email."', '".$nome_imagem."')");



            // Se os dados forem inseridos com sucesso

            // if ($sql){

            //  echo "Você foi cadastrado com sucesso.";

            // }

        }



        // Se houver mensagens de erro, exibe-as

        if (count($error) != 0) {

            foreach ($error as $erro) {

                echo $erro . "<br />";

            }

        }

    }



$query = "INSERT INTO anuncios (titulo, foto, texto) VALUES ('{$titulo}', '{$caminho_imagem}', '{$texto}')";

$inserir = mysqli_query($connect,$query);





if ($inserir) {

  echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript' TYPE='text/javascript'>

          location.href='things.php';

        </SCRIPT>";

} else {

  echo "Não foi possível cadastrar, tente novamente.";

  // Exibe dados sobre o erro:

  echo "Dados sobre o erro:" . mysqli_error($connect);

}
```

Comment: Tem algum tutorial de como faz para colocar os contratos em pdf dentro do banco de dados?

Comment: Voce pode usar o metodo de upload de arquivo do PHP. 
  Ele pode copiar um arquivo para uma outra pasta renomeandoo ou não e devolvendo o caminho, podend ser armazenado em uma variavel para cadastro no banco, fiz um com imagens vou lhe enviar o codigo https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php